# Convert Base64 image to UIImage iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, base64

I am trying to convert a Base64 image to an `UIImage` in `Objective C`.

I am doing something like so :-

```
(UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
  return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

But this function always returns `nil`.

My Base64 string is like so :-

https://pastebin.com/pwbvhN0G

I verified the validity of the image using https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter# and it displayed fine.

**EDIT**
P.S I also include the `data:image/png;base64` in the string.

Is there a way I can fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it like below:

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *base64String = @"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAACWCAYAAAAonXpvAAAQD0lEQVR4Xu3cu4slxRoA8L7BsswgO4GiYGAggpEIIig+MBRTExEfiCgGiiCoIOIDBQ0FUcFYDfQfEGM1FYQVNBGTVQQN1mBlFdlL9bXPPTN75kz16Vc9fgsDOzvV3VW/r7q/qu/07H/Onj176eLFi82pU6ea06dPt1/h7/4QIECAAAECaQr8/fffTcjd4Sv8PeTu/5w7d+7Stdde2/zxxx/N+fPn26/w5+DgoP06c+ZMmqPRKwIECBAgUJHAtjz9888//z+hr5v8+eefq+R+4cKFQ8nd7r2i2WOoBAgQILCYQNh5ryfx/f39VT7e29s71K9jE/p6qz4nXGzULkyAAAECBAoQ2HVDHZXQj/oozRcwYwyBAAECBJIRGCOv7pTQleaTmQM6QoAAAQIZCkxR+R6c0JXmM5xJukyAAAECswvsWkqP7eioCV1pPpZdOwIECBCoQWCMUnqs06QJXWk+NgzaESBAgEAJAlOU0mNdZkvoSvOxIdGOAAECBHISmLqUHmuxSEJXmo8Nj3YECBAgkKLAnKX02PEnkdCV5mPDpR0BAgQILCGwZCk9drzJJXSl+djQaUeAAAECUwqkUkqPHWPSCV1pPjaM2hEgQIDAGAIpltJjx5VVQleajw2rdgQIECAQI5BDKT1mHKFNtgldaT42xNoRIECAQA0bwiISutK8m5UAAQIEtgnkXEqPjWyRCb2GlVhsgLUjQIBAjQIlldJj41d8Qleaj50K2hEgQCBvgdzeSh9bu6qErjQ/9vRxPgIECCwrUEMpPVa46oSuNB87TbQjQIBAGgI1ltJj5SX0DVImTOz00Y4AAQLTC9ReSo8VltAjpJR0IpA0IUCAwIgCnrv9MSX0nmZWij3BNCdAgECEgMpoBNIJTST0AYYm4AA8hxIgUL2ADdK4U0BCH9FTiWhETKciQKBIAc/J6cIqoU9ka+U5EazTEiCQlYBK5nzhktBnsDahZ0B2CQIEkhGwoVkmFBL6Au5KTguguyQBApMKeK5Nyht1cgk9imm6Rlay09k6MwEC0wmoPE5nu+uZJfRd5SY4zg0yAapTEiAwmoANyGiUk5xIQp+EdZyTKmGN4+gsBAjsLuA5tLvd3EdK6HOL73g9K+Md4RxGgEAvAZXCXlxJNZbQkwpHXGfccHFOWhEgECdgwxDnlHorCT31CEX0T0ksAkkTAgQOCXhulDchJPTCYmqlXVhADYfASAIqeyNBJnwaCT3h4Aztmht4qKDjCeQtYIGfd/z69l5C7yuWcXsltoyDp+sEIgXc55FQBTaT0AsMasyQrNxjlLQhkL6ASlz6MZqrhxL6XNIJX8cDIeHg6BqBDQIW5KbFJgEJ3by4TEDJzqQgkJ6A+zK9mKTWIwk9tYgk1h87gcQCojvVCKicVRPq0QYqoY9GWf6JPGDKj7ERLitgAb2sf+5Xl9Bzj+CC/VcCXBDfpYsRcB8VE8rFByKhLx6CMjpgZ1FGHI1iegGVrumNa72ChF5r5CcctwfWhLhOnaWABW+WYcuu0xJ6diHLr8NKivnFTI+HC5j3ww2doZ+AhN7PS+uBAnYqAwEdnqyAylSyoammYxJ6NaFOb6AegOnFRI/6CVig9vPSeloBCX1aX2fvIaBE2QNL08UEzNPF6F34BAEJ3RRJUsDOJ8mwVNkplaQqw57loCX0LMNWV6c9UOuKdwqjtaBMIQr60FdAQu8rpv3iAkqei4egyA6YV0WGtapBSehVhbu8wdpJlRfTuUak8jOXtOvMJSChzyXtOpMLeEBPTpz9BSwAsw+hAWwRkNBNj2IFlFCLDW2vgZkHvbg0zlhAQs84eLoeL2BnFm+Ve0uVmtwjqP+7Ckjou8o5LlsBD/xsQ3dsxy3YyoupEfUXkND7mzmiMAEl2TwDKm55xk2vpxOQ0KezdeYMBez00g2aykq6sdGzNAQk9DTioBcJCkggywfFAmv5GOhBPgISej6x0tOFBZR45wkA53mcXaU8AQm9vJga0QwCdo7jIauEjGfpTHULSOh1x9/oRxCQkPojWhD1N3MEgZMEJPSThPycQE8BJePNYFx6TiTNCfQUkNB7gmlOoI9AzTtRlYs+M0VbAsMFJPThhs5AIEqghgRX8wImahJoRGBCAQl9QlynJrBNoJQSdCnjMFsJ5C4goeceQf0vQiCnnW0NlYYiJpVBVCcgoVcXcgNOXSDFhJnTgiP1+OofgakEJPSpZJ2XwEgCS5W0l7ruSGxOQ6A6AQm9upAbcM4CU+6UU6wM5BwrfScwt4CEPre46xEYSWCMBDzlAmGkYToNAQKRAhJ6JJRmBFIXiC2Rx7ZLfbz6R4DAYQEJ3YwgUKDA0Z333t5eO8rw7/v7+83BwUH71f17gQSGRKA6AQm9upAbcA0CEnoNUTZGAnbo5gCBIgViS+mx7YpEMigCBQvYoRccXEMrW8BLcWXH1+gI9BWQ0PuKaU9gQYEp30ofY4GwII1LE6heQEKvfgoASF1gqRL5UtdNPR76RyBVAQk91cjoV7UCKe6Up6wMVBtoAycwsoCEPjKo0xHYRSCnhJnigmMXc8cQKE1AQi8tosaTjUApJe1SxpHNxNFRAscISOimBoGZBGrY2eZUaZgp7C5DYDYBCX02aheqUaDmBFfDAqbGOW3M6QpI6OnGRs8yFVCC3hw4LplOaN3ORkBCzyZUOpqqgJ1o/8jUXLnor+UIAnECEnqck1YEDglISONNCAui8SydqW4BCb3u+Bt9DwEl4x5YA5pyHoDn0KoFJPSqw2/w2wTsHJefHyohy8dAD/IRkNDziZWeziAggcyAvOMlLLB2hHNYNQISejWhNtDjBJR485wb4pZn3PR6OgEJfTpbZ05UwE4v0cAM6JbKygA8hxYjIKEXE0oD2SbggV/P/LBgqyfWRnpYQEI3I4oVUJItNrS9BmYe9OLSOGMBCT3j4On6YQE7MzPiJAGVmpOE/DxnAQk95+jpe+MBbRLsKmABuKuc41IVkNBTjYx+HSughGpyTCFgXk2h6pxzCkjoc2q71k4CdlI7sTlogIDKzwA8hy4mIKEvRu/C2wQ8UM2PVAQsKFOJhH6cJCChnyTk57MJKHnORu1CAwTM0wF4Dp1UQEKflNfJtwnY+ZgfuQuoJOUewbL6L6GXFc/kR+MBmHyIdHBHAQvUHeEcNpqAhD4apRMdJ6BEaW7UKGDe1xj1ZccsoS/rX+TV7VSKDKtBDRBQmRqA59BoAQk9mkrDbQIeWOYHgTgBC944J636C0jo/c0c8a+AkqKpQGC4gPtouKEz/E9AQjcTogXsLKKpNCSwk4BK105sDvpXQEI3FbYKeMCYIASWEbCAXsY956tK6DlHb6K+KwFOBOu0BAYIuC8H4FVyqIReSaC3DdNOwCQgkJeAylle8ZqrtxL6XNKJXccDIbGA6A6BHQUsyHeEK/AwCb3AoB43JCW7ioJtqNUKuM+rDb233EsOvZV7ydE1NgInC6jEnWxUUgs79JKi2TSNG7iwgBoOgZEELPBHgkz4NBJ6wsGJ7ZoSW6yUdgQIdAKeG+XNBQk9w5haaWcYNF0mkLCAyl7CwenRNQm9B9aSTd1wS+q7NoF6BGwY8o21hJ5w7JTEEg6OrhGoRMBzKJ9AS+gJxcrKOKFg6AoBApcJqBSmPSkk9IXj4wZZOAAuT4DATgI2IDuxTXqQhD4p7+aTK2EtgO6SBAhMKuC5Nilv1Mkl9CimYY2sZIf5OZoAgbwEVB6XiZeEPpG7CT0RrNMSIJCVgA3NfOGS0Ee0VnIaEdOpCBAoUsBzcrqwSugDbK08B+A5lACB6gVUMsedAhJ6T08TsCeY5gQIEIgQsEGKQDqhiYQeYahEFIGkCQECBEYU8NztjymhbzCzUuw/kRxBgACBqQRURuNkJfR/nUyYuAmjFQECBJYUsOE6Xr/qhK6ks+Rt6doECBAYLuA5/n/DqhK6ld3wm8cZCBAgkKpA7ZXW4hN67QFO9cbTLwIECEwpUOMGrsiErgQz5W3i3AQIEMhPoIa8UERCr3Ellt/tpMcECBBIQ6DUym22Cb3UgKQx3fWCAAECdQiUtCHMKqHXUDKp4xYySgIECKQpkHOeSTqhl7RySnPq6hUBAgQIHCeQWyU4uYSeG6BbgQABAgTyFvj666+bu+66azWIm2++ufn000+bG2+8sf23N998s3n11Vfbv3/22WfNDTfc0Ozv7zcHBwfN559/3jz++OPtzz7++OPmoYceisYI+e65555rHnnkkebOO+9sj+v+7cMPP1yd54033mheeeWV9vsffviheeCBB5pvv/22eeqpp5p33nmn2dvba3+WRELPucQRHTkNCRAgQCBJgU8++aT58ccfV0lzvZMh2YeEHtp8//33q7+fOnWq+eabb5qXX365eemll5orrrii/dkHH3ywWghsG+x64v7qq69WCf33339vnnnmmeb111+/7DzdMXfffXdz//33t4uB8PduEbFIQldKT3JO6xQBAgSqFAiJ+Prrr9+4uw4/C3/CDvnojjok+S+//LJ56623mr/++qt5++23m6uvvrp58MEH2937mTNnmpD4j/7pdtm3335789NPP7Xn7nbo4Wchmb/33nvNlVdeeejQ8LNnn322effdd9tkHxYbH3300WqXPltCV0qv8j4xaAIECCQtsKns3XV4fUccdsFHv19P9uGY8P0///zTPPnkk80LL7zQJvmQrK+55pq2NB/K+GEREM4T/oRSeTjvekI/mqSPqxaEZL9ePQjfT5rQldKTnsc6R4AAgeoFQok7JNUvvvhiZdF9Fr4p2a/v5o/u7NdL992xt956a/uZe1eaD5/Pd7v37trrCT2c4+GHH1715d57720XAV0CX9+RH93Nj5rQldKrvzcAECBAICuBrvz9/vvvt2Xv9e9vueWWy15ai03oAWH9BbawSAife58/f779unDhQnPp0qV2Jx9euLvnnntat3D+c+fOrcro69+Hz+wnTehK6VnNXZ0lQIAAgRMEulL6888/f+jFs5iSezh190b6pgTdXTpsgMPn50888UTz2GOPNXfccUe7cw9f3Vvr3aKg+9z8t99+W72UN1rJXSnd/UCAAAECpQoctwvf9FLc+tvxR0vw4TPup59+uv0M/dFHH73spbv1kvtNN9202r0H1y65//LLL6uX5EJCX39hbqeX4pTSS522xkWAAIG6BY6+WNYl4e730I/7tbWwQ15/6zworr+Bvp6sr7rqqkM/68SPfobeLRhuu+225r777mt+/fXXdkd+3XXXtZ/BhzfmX3zxxfZX1Xr92ppSet2T3OgJECBQi8DR/1hm/ffCu7J59x/LHP3Z+kts3ct0XaIOn8l35ffQLnz+3b3gFs676aW4o/+xTHhj/rXXXmsuXrzY7uBDkg8fBXz33Xfb/2MZpfRapq9xEiBAgECOAtvydPuW+9mzZy+F7B+286dPn26/Nv0yfI6D12cCBAgQIFCiQPg4POTu8BX+HnL3fwGAyHYzePzAEQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64String];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    self.imgView.image = image;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still get `imageData` as null.

Comment: I have checked your base64 image from my side, its working  check my update i have upload screen @user3034944

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is working with the base64 image I mentioned in the question, but does not work with another base64 image

Comment: bit confusing, please share your code so i can understand @user3034944

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the basic Apple developer tutorial,you can get the answer.But below the exact answer.

```
NSData *dataEncoded = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncoded  options:0]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataEncoded];
```

Also find the solution here [Converting UIImage to NSData and NSData to NSString for posting images to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301142/converting-uiimage-to-nsdata-and-nsdata-to-nsstring-for-posting-images-to-a-serv)